# Apache, on 404 from mod_rewrite, check file system for file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, drupal

At the moment, I'm migrating a site, and due to time constraints, we've migrated most to a CMS (Drupal), but still have some flat HTML sub sites that need to get served outside of this.

Now, config wise, I've setup Apache to pass requests for files that do exist and get served directly, rather than sending the request to the CMS:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

As we get more time, the team would like to slowly import the pages we've left out of the CMS from the file system, but we don't have the ability to easily delete those additional files from the file system once we've imported them to Drupal (service provider deploy method unfortunately - so not changable).

We're using the same URLs as the old site (maintaining legacy links/addresses and all that), so once we've recreated the page in the CMS, the above rewrite rule is still going to serve the page from the file system.

What I would like to do to get around this, is route all requests through Drupal using mod_rewrite, then if Drupal throws a 404, attempt to pull the URL from the file system, rather than what we have currently, which is if the file exists, serve that automatically. From a day or so of searching, I can't find a way of achieving this, can't even really find a lot of people having run into this issue before actually.

Naturally, if I had full control over our environment, it would be easy to just delete the underlying files once they've been migrated, but that's not so simple in this case.

I also understand doing this will incur an overhead, but given this will only apply for a small part of the site, I'll be evaluating any solutions to see whether it is an acceptable compromise.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It may not matter but is this d6 or 7?
Also what are these static files? Are they single html files or more complex microsites? 
Are there very many of them?

Comment: Your demand is not yet sufficiently detailed.

Comment: @Andrew It's D7, the files are all single HTML files that it is serving, some use SSI but that's as complex as it gets.

Comment: @jacouh, what part did't you understand? I'll explain it in more detail if you let me know what part to expand on. I'm after an Apache based solution that allows me to route all traffic first to Drupal, then when a 404 is thrown, Apache tries looking up the file on the file system, serving it if it finds it, otherwise showing a 404 to the end user. I've played around with Apache's ErrorDocument, but didn't have much success.

Comment: I'm thinking ErrorDocument pointing to a PHP script that then does the checking of whether the file exists or not is going to be the most effective option.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a RewriteCond that will kick in before what you have there that checks for specific paths and sends them directly to index.php?

Something like

```
RewriteRule ^/some/path/to/file.html$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It might get kind of unwieldy if you have a lot of disparate paths, it would be nicer if your existing static files had a nice regexable pattern

Comment: Unfortunately, there are quite a few paths. That also doesn't quite work (I tried a variant of that early in the process) because once it gets sent to Drupal, Drupal then throws a 404, and aside from using ErrorDocument, I couldn't get Apache to process that 404.

Comment: Okay so the paths to the drupalised version of the static page don't correspond exactly? Otherwise I don't understand why drupal would throw a 404